# How to access theme config via app scripts in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is there an option to access the theme config in app scripts?

As far as I unterstand only store config and config.xml configs are accessible:
https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/System/SystemConfig/Facade/SystemConfigFacade.php

Does it make sense here to get access via the theme repository with:
https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Facade/RepositoryFacade.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should access the theme config over the repository facade. There is no shorthand for that.